# Determine whether $S \cap T$ is closed and bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $$S=\{x\in \mathbb{R} : \text{ } x^6-x^5 \leq 100\}$$

$$T=\{x^2-2x : \text{ } x\in (0, \infty)\}$$

Determine wether $ S \cap T$ is closed and bounded?

My Try

$S$ is bounded hence $ S \cap T$ is also bounded.

$S=[a,b]$ where $a<-1$ because -1 satisfy the equation given.  and $T=(-1, \infty)$ hence $ S \cap T=[-1,b]$

Hence $ S \cap T$ is closed and bounded

However I am not satisfied with my reasoning.
Can anyone tell me the proper solution.

Comment: Why is $T=(-2,\infty)$? And if it were the case, would there not be $S \cap T=(-2,b]$?

Comment: In the title you ask for open or closed, in the body you ask for closed and bounded. Which is it?

Comment: Note that $T=[-1,\infty)$.

Comment: @cristoph Its closed and bounded

Comment: You have to justify why $S$ is a bounded interval, and your formula for $T$ is incorrect, take $x=1$ in the defining set.

Answer (score 1):

Let $s(x) = x^6-x^5$, since $s$ is continuous, $S=s^{-1} ((-\infty, 100])$ is closed.

Since $s(x) \to \infty$ as $|x| \to \infty$ we see that $S$ is bounded, hence compact.

Let $t(x) = x^2-2x = x(x-2)$, differentiating shows that $t$ has a $\min$ of $-1$. at $x=1$,
and we see that $t(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Hence $T=[-1,\infty)$, which is
closed.

Hence $T \cap S$ is closed.